# Angular Router Module ActivatedRoute returns null firstChild when one exists

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Following one of Todd Motto's excellent guides (https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events) I came across a situation that I can't explain.

Here's some code:

```
this.router.events
    .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
    .map((route) => {
        console.log('route pre-while: ', route); // Shows ActivatedRoute object
        console.log('pre-while route child: ', route.firstChild); // null
        while (route.firstChild) {
          console.log('while route: ', route);
          route = route.firstChild;
        }
        console.log('post while route: ', route);
        return route;
      })
    .subscribe((elem) => {
        console.log('elem: ', elem);
    });
```

In this code block, the 'route pre-while' log statement shows an ActivatedRoute object in Chrome console.  If I expand the object in Chrome's console window, I can click on the `firstChild` attribute and see another `ActivatedRoute` object, which is as I expect.  However, the problem is, that the second log statement 'pre-while route child' outputs `null` to the console.  Also, the WHILE loop never executs because `route.firstChild` evaluates to `null`.  Can anyone explain to me why this is???  Why can I log the object and see a `firstChild`, but then immediately get null when trying to access it?

Comment: my bad, I saw that you removed it for me.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to make sure you understood why.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for asking the question and figuring out the solution by yourself.

for the people landing here in future, this would be the working solutions.

```js
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

.
.

constructor(
        ...
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

.
.

this.router.events
    .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
    .map((route) => {
        console.log('route pre-while: ', route); // Shows ActivatedRoute object
        console.log('pre-while route child: ', route.firstChild); // null
        while (route.firstChild) {
          console.log('while route: ', route);
          route = route.firstChild; // Conditional if needed in scenario
        }
        console.log('post while route: ', route);
        return route;
      })
    .subscribe((elem) => {
        console.log('elem: ', elem);
    });
```

Comment: When attempting the above with Angular 10, tslint says:
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'

Answer (score 3):

So, it turns out that the actual router event matters.  Intercepting on the NavigationStart event doesn't give enough time to populate the ActivatedRoute object.  It's too early.  Intercepting on NavigationEnd seems to be the ticket since all of the evaluating and loading of routes has been done by then.